# Aysnc : doPostExceute() is getting even before doInBackground() in android

Tags: android, asynchronous

I am using `AsyncTask` to do background processing i.e I'm fetching the data from the server and storing in the `List` in `doInBackground()` method. I'm using this stored data in `onPostExecute()`.

The problem that I'm facing is the `onPostExceute()` is getting executed even before `doInBackground()` is done it's execution.

Can someone suggest what might be going wrong ?

Code:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> read= new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        ProgressDialog progress= new ProgressDialog(LastData.this);
        ArrayList<String> testData;
        DBAdapter db;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progress.setTitle("Please Wait");
            testData= new ArrayList<String>();
            db= new DBAdapter(LastData.this);
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progress.setMessage("Fetching Data !!");
            progress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Details");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
                public void done(List<ParseObject> dataList,
                        ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.d("Details", "Retrieved " + dataList.size()
                                + " scores");
                        for (int idx = 0; idx < dataList.size(); idx++) {
                            data.add(dataList.get(idx).get("fname")
                                    .toString());
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }

                    for (int idx = 0; idx < data.size(); idx++) {
                        testData.add(data.get(idx));
                    }

                    System.out.println("size inside is " + testData.size());
                }

            });

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progress.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(LastData.this, "Size is "+testData.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

read.execute();
```

`Toast` meassage in `onPostExecute()` is getting displayed even before the `doInBackground` method is exceuted.

Comment: are there any Async tasks in your doInBackground() method?  Everything needs to be synchronous otherwise it will just fire off the request and complete the rest of the work before your task has finished.

Comment: em fetching data from the Parse server by querying as shown in the code, No idea whether that is Asynchronous process or not.

Answer (score 1):

If `onPostExceute` is executed even before `doInBackground` completes the task then it means you are probably making an `asynchronous` call inside `doInBackground`. Please post code for a more specific answer.

**EDIT:**

The problem is that `findInBackground` runs asynchronously so you don't need an AsynTask to call it. It already will run without blocking your thread and `FindCallback` will be called when it finds something. So you need to remove the AsyncTask and find the place where you call `read.execute(...)` and replace it as follows:

1) put code from `onPreExecute()` and `doInBackground()` there
2) put code from `onPostExecute` to the end of `FindCallback()`

Example:

```
        /*...*/
        progress.setTitle("Please Wait");
        testData= new ArrayList<String>();
        db= new DBAdapter(LastData.this);
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.setMessage("Fetching Data !!");
        progress.show();
        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Details");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> dataList,
                    ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("Details", "Retrieved " + dataList.size()
                            + " scores");
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < dataList.size(); idx++) {

                        data.add(dataList.get(idx).get("fname")
                                .toString());
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }


                for (int idx = 0; idx < data.size(); idx++) {

                    testData.add(data.get(idx));
                }
                System.out.println("size inside is " + testData.size());
                progress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(LastData.this, "Size is "+testData.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
        /*...*/
```

Comment: man , it works brilliantly after i making the changes u said !! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

looks like

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() { ... }
```

is some kind of async task. I assume that there is a method

```
 query.find()
```

which is synchronous.

Comment: yes it is an asynchronous method, i was enclosing asynchronous method inside async, i completely removed async. now it works brilliantly. thanks for commenting .

Comment: then you can accept this answer. Not for the 15 rep. points I get but for people with the same problem which will find their answer more easily.